# Unable to import MixPanel Analytics library in Android App in Eclipse

Tags: android, mixpanel

I am trying to integrate Mixpanel Android SDK in Eclipse using [these](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/android) instructions. The error

I have Mixpanel imported as library in the workspace and my app points to mixpanel-android project as a Library, but I still the issue below.
[image]

Below is a window showing that i do have mixpanel-android imported in Eclipse.
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the answer, hope it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have imported Mixpanel SDK project to your workspace, i would like to again repeat the steps and further details too.
You should add Mixpanel SDK to your workspace first and mark it as a library,

[SDK link](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android)

SDK library details
[Library Details](http://prntscr.com/80nsja)

Your project library details
[Your project imports](http://prntscr.com/80nte1), even add mixpanel SDK to java build path library